# Render view from another view : controller not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing a litte blog like application and at the moment I'm facing a problem that I can't resolve.

I have 2 models at the moment :
1. Post
2. Comment

I can already manage my posts without difficulties but I have some problems with comments. I chose to make a relation has_many / belongs_to between my post and my comment models. I'd like to display all the comments related to a post when the user is on the post's page. My erb looks like this :

```
#some code
#...
#...
#render the comments
<%= render :template => "comments/index", :locals => {:post_id => @post.id} %>
```

My problem here is that the method index from my CommentsController is never called. I put some puts in the index method and they are never displayed in the console.

Should I use another tag to render the view ? Is there another way to do this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `render`s only views.

Comment: `render` only renders the view. It does not hit the related controller and action.

Comment: Hum, I see, So how am I supposed to do that to have to desired behaviour ?

Comment: May be you can render it as partial.

Answer (score 0):

If the post view is the only page to show comments, you don't have to call `comments/index` to get comments, just show comments when rendering the post view, for example

In your post view

```
#some code
#...
# render comments
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.content%>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Or put them in a partial with a `post` parameter if comments are used in many views

In app/views/partials/_comments.html.erb

```
# render comments
<% post.comments.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.content%>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

and render this partial where you want to show comments:

```
#some code
#...
# render comments
<%= render partial: "partials/comments", locals: { post: @post } %>
```

Using `comments/index` to get comments and showing them in a view is more likely the frondend tech such as Javascript/AJAX to load page parts dynamically. In this case, the `comments/index` is more likely an API call(render a JSON format instead of a html view).

Comment: Yeah but I'd like to have the comments list and the a form to add comment that's why I wanted to split all that things in different views.

Comment: I think you should separate them into partials, not views. A view can contain many partials, but cannot contain views. You can put the comment list in one partial and the comment form in the other. In this case, the `CommentsController#new` and `CommentsController#index` actions are not used, the variables used in the partials should put in the `PostsController#show`.

Comment: I'm gonna try this way. I though that split the code had been better.